# Regular function call

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I’m doing something like a bank and the question arose, is it possible to somehow track that if more than a year has passed since the moment any operation was performed on the account (card), then the account (card) was transferred to an inactive status? It is clear that you can take the date and simply compare it with today, but you need to somehow call it regularly, every day. And here is the question itself, is there some kind of annotation in the spring that will run regularly with a certain period of time

Comment: Now what would `@Scheduled` do...

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks  @Scheduled